# Why not turn off the main engines while using the launch escape system on liquid fuelled engines?

Tags: engines, safety, launch-escape-system

I've seen a couple of launch escape systems firing and the rockets main engines are on, isn't it more safe if you turn off the engines? Edit: i agree that the engines turning off might be not so gentle and that if you immediately stop the fuel that it might explode but what about slowly reducing the amount of propellant gradually then when it hits the least amount of thrust turning it off? And on the launch escape system test by the new shepherd a rocket which it's engines are meant to be turned off and on again but when the test happens the engine is still firing, in my opinion if there's a problem detected in the rocket the most important priority is to get the crew as far away from the big container of chemicals that can explode with great force as fast as possible

Comment: A guess: launch escape systems are used when things are going badly wrong; being unable to turn off the booster engines is part of what can go wrong, so you test the LES with the worst-case scenario.

Comment: In addition, the circuitry which turns the engines off when something goes wrong can itself malfunction and turn the engines off when it should not have.

Comment: If the first stage begins to disintegrate and will explode soon you can't stop that by turning off the engines. Getting away as fast and soon as possible is top priority for the launch escape system. Turning off the main engines as fast as possible may cause an explosion. The huge mass of propellants rushing through the pipes from the tanks to the engines can't be stoped immediately without destroying the pipes.

Comment: @Uwe by this logic you could never shut down an engine in flight, yet we know that Saturns did this routinely.

Comment: @OrganicMarble If you can't stop the fluids immediately, you may do it gradually during a small time interval. Or redirect the fluid stream to the tanks. Something has to be done to prevent a [hydraulic shock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Water_hammer). Don't close a shut down valve immediately, do it slowly instead.

Comment: A well designed engine has a graceful shutdown.

Comment: Oh, you're talking about the New Shepard test. In that case, they wanted to keep control of the first stage in order to do an intact powered landing; while they could have stopped and restarted the engines, it was likely easier to keep the engines burning.

Comment: @RussellBorogove The worst case scenario is a rapid unplanned disassembly of the launch vehicle. The RUD would essentially do the engine shutdown, but not according to any plan.

Answer (score 10):

Great idea! The Apollo designers agreed.  The Emergency Detection System / Abort Sequencer would indeed shut down the engines when the appropriate abort was called.  Shutdown of the engines was inhibited for the first 40 seconds after liftoff so that the vehicle wouldn't fall back onto the pad.

> The  subsystem  is  activated  automatically  by  the  emergency
> detection  system  in  the  first  100  seconds  or  manually  by  the
> astronauts  at  any  time  from  the  pad  to  jettison  altitude.
> ...............................
>
> After  receiving  an abort signal,  the booster  is  cut  off  (after
> 40  seconds  of flight),  the CM-SM  separation  charges  fired,
> and  the  launch  escape  motor  ignited.  The  launch  escape  motor
> lifts the CM and  the pitch control  motor  (used only at low
> altitudes)  directs  the flight path off to the side.
> ...............................
>
> The  emergency   detection  system  operates  from  the  time  of
> umbilical  separation  until  100  seconds  after  liftoff.  It  is
> designed  to  detect  emergency  conditions  of  the  launch  vehicle,
> display  the  information  to  the  astronauts,  and,  if  the
> system  is  on  automatic,  start  an  abort.  Under  certain
> conditions  (excessive  vehicle  rates  or  two  booster  engines
> out),  the  system  initiates  an  abort  signal.  This  signal
> resets  the  event  timer,  activates  the  launch  escape  subsystem,
> and  (after  30  to  40  seconds  of  flight)  cuts  off  the  launch
> vehicle  engines.  A  "lockout"  system  prevents  the  emergency
> detection  system  from  operating  before  liftoff.

[source](https://www.hq.nasa.gov/alsj/CSM15_Launch_Escape_Subsystem_pp137-146.pdf) (pp. 137-139)

[image]

[source](http://web.mit.edu/digitalapollo/Documents/Chapter5/saturnas501.pdf) (highlighting mine)