# From attitude control malfunction to launch escape Go signal?

Tags: space-shuttle, saturn-v, launch-escape, sequencing-logic

I’ve seen and read about launch failures caused by crossed thrust vectoring wires which fed rock and tilt commands to the wrong engine gimbal actuators (rock command going to tilt cylinder and tilt command going to rock cylinder).

This has happened both in stage 1 and stage 2 flight.

And as you can imagine the rocket would go wildly out of control in no time.

And this has me wondering: suppose this happened on a crewed rocket. There must be logic in place to fire the launch escape system immediately if the rocket is veering wildly out of control.

And that logic would probably take in some sensor reading, compare it to some critical threshold, and trigger launch escape if the threshold is exceeded.

But what would that sensor reading be: attitude error (in roll/pitch/yaw)? Attitude error *rate* (angular velocity for roll/pitch/yaw)? Attitude error acceleration? Other?

And what would the critical threshold be to fire launch escape? E.g., 30 deg off target? 30 deg/s? 30 deg/s2?

No, I don’t have a good intuition for what a reasonable threshold would be :D

Huge thanks if you know and can share or point me to a place where I can find an answer! Any info on public rockets like the space shuttle and Saturn V would be very very welcome.

Note: this question will seem very very similar to a previous question I’ve asked. But this question is specific to just one narrow type of malfunction—loss of attitude control (as opposed to engine failure or any other failure mode). So here I’m less interested in how to go from malfunction detection to launch escape activation... and more interested in what variable you’d monitor to detect an attitude control malfunction and what the critical threshold might be to fire the launch escape system.

Comment: Check the left hand side of this drawing right above where it says S-IVB Stage https://i.stack.imgur.com/DEqYA.png

Comment: Ah! That’s the schematic from an earlier post! Sorry, I clearly didn’t stare at it closely enough ( I’m jam-packed with papers to read and things to fix in my model and keeping a backlog of all the things to look back at).

Comment: And yes! I see they had a two-engine threshold for launch escape firing? I already gots that in my model. It’s nice to see it in a schematic for a real rocket, so that it’s not just my best guess anymore.

Comment: And I see that yes there is an attitude rate trigger for launch escape! Now I just a number for that rate. Maybe I’ll find it in the schematic if I stare at it a bit more.

Comment: There it is! 5 deg/s in pitch and yaw and 20 deg/s in roll! Aha! I can only assume this is attitude *error* rate. Even still, I wouldn’t have imagined 5 deg/s. Seems so low! Then again, thrust vector controllers have a lot of control authority so you should never be diverging from your pitch schedule by 5deg/s, I guess? This is just the thing I needed anyhow. Thank you thank you

Comment: @OrganicMarble: what is that 40 s... override period I think it was? Can’t double-check just now, but there was some kind of period given there. Does that mean the rocket would keep going for a full 40 s after the attitude rate crosses over the rate threshold? 40 s is long enough to crash a malfunctioning rocket, ha ha. I guess the crew could always be counted on to confirm launch escape is a go?

Comment: 40 seconds was a lock-out during which the booster engines wouldn't be shut down if an abort triggered, to try and keep the wreckage off the pad. See https://space.stackexchange.com/a/33699/6944